# Failing to add newly created cocoa pod to private pod spec

Tags: ios, swift, git, cocoapods

I'm following to following tutorial - [How to Create a CocoaPod in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift).

I'm stuck at the last step - **Using Your New CocoaPod**

> You first need to add your Podspec to a private specs repo; this lets
>   CocoaPods find the pod when you try to install it. Fortunately, you’ve
>   already created a Git repo for this, so this final step is relatively
>   straightforward.
>
> Enter the following in Terminal, making sure you’re still in the
>   RWPickFlavor directory:

```
pod repo add RWPodSpecs [Your RWPodSpecs Git URL]
pod repo push RWPodSpecs RWPickFlavor.podspec
```

I get this fatal error:

**fatal: destination path 'RWPodSpecs' already exists and is not an empty directory.**

I've removed the repo and created it again according to the "Setting Up Your GitHub Repo" tutorial step. But I get this error still.

Any ideas?

Comment: @shadowsheep the push command

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? ^^ please if it has helped you deserve me something for the time I’ve spent to help you.

Comment: @shadowsheep I'll set a reminder for 2 days and grant you a bounty in 2 days. (You can do this after 2 days the question is alive). Again, thank you, man. Both your answers helped me.

Comment: Wow! That’s really nice of you. Thanks so much. I didn’t even know that could be done. Btw, glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory you are looking for is in your **home directory** inside this folder

```
.cocoapods/repos/
```

So you chan find your local repos here:

```
~/.cocoapods/repos/
```

Check it out and you will see that you already have the `RWPodSpecs` folder here.

Maybe it has been created once before while you are following the tutorial.

Back it up and remove it.

Then start over.

> `pod repo add`
>   [reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_repo_add).

Comment: I did start over. Even started another tutorial https://medium.com/@ziadtamim/how-to-create-your-private-library-pod-with-cocoapods-9efa864511fd. I get failure at the same place. But now I get:  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fuxlud@gmail.com/Snorlax.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400

Comment: @Luda That's another issue. I'll made the tutorial you have written in your post from **raywenderlich** and all has worked fine. I tell you for sure that the problem of your post "The directory already exists" depends from what I've told you in my answer.

Comment: @Luda Indeed [this git repo](https://github.com/fuxlud@gmail.com/Snorlax/) there exists no more.

Comment: Now I see, it added to @gmail.com to my username in github. I'll try again

Comment: You got your bounty! Happy new year!

Comment: Thank you so much! Gr8 interaction! Happy new year!